# Querydsl java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: spring, querydsl

I am trying to retrieve data from account table where ninstid = 60 using Querydsl. But I am getting following Exception.

**AccountModel**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class AccountModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "account_seq_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="account_seq_generator", sequenceName = "account_seq")
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public Integer naccountid;
    public String namount;
    public String sacctdesc;
    public Integer naccountcpcmappingid;
    public Integer nindirectcostrate;
    public Integer nagencyid ;
    public Integer ndeptid ;
    public String sgrantnum;
    public Timestamp dstartdate;
    public Timestamp denddate;  
    public String slocation;
    public String sclientacctid;
    public Integer ninvestigatorid;
    public Integer ninstid;
    public Integer ntempaccountid;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="ndeptid",insertable =  false, updatable = false)
    public DepartmentModel department;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="ninvestigatorid",insertable =  false, updatable = false)
    public InvestigatorModel investigator;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})  
    @JoinColumn(name="naccountcpcmappingid",insertable =  false, updatable = false)
    public AccountCPCMappingModel accountCPC;
```

**AccountService**

```
public Set<AccountModel> gridLoad() {

        QAccountModel accountModel = QAccountModel.accountModel;
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);      
                 query.from(accountModel)
                      .where(accountModel.ninstid.eq(60));

        return  (Set<AccountModel>) query.fetchAll();       
    }
```

**I am getting following Exception**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery cannot be cast to java.util.Set
```

I am new to querydsl. Can any one help me?

Comment: so dont cast it to a Set, when it is a "JPAQuery". Basic java http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/apidocs/com/querydsl/jpa/JPAQueryBase.html#fetchAll--

Comment: I got answer thank you.

Comment: But I am getting all column. How to select particular column

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<AccountModel> gridLoad() {

        QAccountModel accountModel = QAccountModel.accountModel;
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);      
                 query.from(accountModel)
                      .where(accountModel.ninstid.eq(60));

        return  query.fetch();         
    }
```